# How can I paginate data in laravel&Vue?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I am making site with laravel and vuejs.
I use complex Eloquent query for getting data from DB as follows.

```
$query->with([
        'deviceAssignment.deviceSetting.sim',
        'deviceAssignment.deviceSetting.device.deviceType',
        'deviceSignal',
        'deviceAssignment.deviceSetting.deviceGroup',
        'deviceAssignment.deviceSetting.company',
        'deviceAssignment.deviceSetting.phones'])
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->get();
```

I use several tables at once, then this size of data is somewhat huge, so I want to paginate this data.
I placed paginator in the bottom of vue component like this.

.......

```
<pager :items="histories" v-on:paginate="changePage" class="pager bottom_10 top_20 position_r"></pager>
```

And changePage function is as follows;

```
methods: {
        changePage: function(page){
            location.href = "/history/setting?page=" + page;
        },
```

In this status, simply, I change get() function to paginate() in the first part to realize pagination.
Am I right?

Comment: i think you should use https://github.com/niiknow/vue-datatables-net as it work with https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Pagination use `paginate(10)` function instead of `get()` function.

```
$query->with([
        'deviceAssignment.deviceSetting.sim',
        'deviceAssignment.deviceSetting.device.deviceType',
        'deviceSignal',
        'deviceAssignment.deviceSetting.deviceGroup',
        'deviceAssignment.deviceSetting.company',
        'deviceAssignment.deviceSetting.phones'])
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->paginate(10);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#paginating-query-builder-results
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#paginating-eloquent-results

Comment: Akshay Salunkhe, Thanks, by the way, When I click pagination button to change page, changePage function is called, will laravel get the only 10 results of $query->with([.........])->orderBy(.......)?

Comment: no 10 is just for example. you can add however you want 10, 15.